# Is the subscriber able to receive updates from multiple publishers in ZeroMQ with cpp binding?

Tags: c++, zeromq, publish-subscribe

In my code I am only able to receive the messages from the first publisher (on port 5556) to which I connect.

So do I need to close the first connection (5556) before connecting to second (5557)?

If so, then in the statement of ZeroMQ guide

> "A subscriber can connect to more than one publisher, using one connect call each time. Data will then arrive and be interleaved ("fair-queued") so that no single publisher drowns out the others."

Does the phrase "*using one connect call each time*" mean we need to close the first connection before connecting to second publisher?

How can I connect to multiple publishers at the same time to receive messages from both.

Code:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
zmq::context_t context (1);
zmq::socket_t subscriber (context, ZMQ_SUB);

subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5557");
subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);//subscribe to all messages

//  Process 10 updates
int update_nbr;
for (update_nbr = 0; update_nbr < 10 ; update_nbr++) {

    zmq::message_t update;
    subscriber.recv (&update);

 // Prints only the data from publisher bound to port 5556

    std::string updt = std::string(static_cast<char*>(update.data()), update.size());
    std::cout << "Received Update/Messages/TaskList " << update_nbr <<" : "<< updt << std::endl;

}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Does it mean we need to close the first before second?

No.

One need not `.close()` so as to launch another call  to the `.connect(...)` method.

---

### How can I connect to multiple `PUB`-s to receive messages from both?

In cases, where both Fair-Queueing **`SUB`**-side Policy and identical  Topic-filter Policy logic processing on **`{ PUB | SUB }`**-side ( version dependent ... ) remains plausible:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
zmq::context_t context (1);
zmq::socket_t subscriber (context, ZMQ_SUB);

subscriber.connect( "tcp://localhost:5556" ); // ipc://first   will have less
subscriber.connect( "tcp://localhost:5557" ); // ipc://second  protocol overheads

subscriber.setsockopt( ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0 );// subscribe to .recv() any message
...
}
```

In cases where it is not, use multiple `SUB`-side socket-instances, each `.connect()`-ed to respective non-balanced **`PUB`**-s and use a non-blocking **`.poll()`** inside an event-loop, tightly engineered so as to ad-hoc monitor and handle all the non-balanced message-arrival event-streams under the non-coherent Topic-filter Policy being processed per each `PUB/SUB` ( or `XPUB/XSUB` ) co-existing message "event-streams".

Comment: Should I write subscriber.connect("ipc://publisher.cpp"); How to mention port number?@user3666197

Comment: No, you should not. No, there is no "*port number*" for **`ipc://`** transport-class connection mechanics. The best next step, in case one wishes to start further experimentation with `ipc://` transport-class deployment, would be to re-read the elementary system documentation on how to setup and configure system resources for this efficient IPC-tool >>> https://linux.die.net/man/1/ipcmk